# Represent a vector in R for sampling that is too large for existing memory

Tags: r

I am generating a data vector to sample from with `sample` without replacement.

If the dataset I am generating from is large enough, the vector exceeds the limits of R.

How can I represent these data in such a way that I can sample without replacement but can still handle huge datasets?

Generating the vector of counts:

```
counts <- vector()
for (i in 1:1024) {
    counts <- c(counts, rep(i, times=data[i,]$readCount))
}
```

Sampling:

```
trial_fn <- function(counts) {
   replicate(num_trials, sample(counts, size=trial_size, replace=F), simplify=F)
}

trials <- trial_fn(counts)

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 32.0 Mb
```

Is there a more sparse or compressed way I can represent this and still be able to sample without replacement?

Comment: At the moment, this is not a limit on vector length.  It's a limit on the available memory.  You'll have to fix that.  Later on, if you've verified your vector is longer than `.Machine$integer.max`, then just make it a `double`, as `.Machine$double.xmax` is rather larger. But you can build a vector of 10^8 elements easily enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your `data` has 1024 rows with different `readCount`. 
The vector you build has the first `readCount` value repeated once, the second `readCount` repeated twice and so on.

Then you want to sample from this vector without replacement. So basically, you're sampling the first readCount with a probability of `1 / sum(1:1024)`, the second readCount with a probability of `2 / sum(1:1024)` and so on, and each time you extract one value, it is removed from the set.

Of course the fastest and easier approach is yours, but you can also do it with much less memory but losing speed (significantly). This can be done by giving probabilities of extraction to `sample` function, extracting one value at a time and manually "removing" the extracted value.

Here's an example :

```
# an example of your data
data <- data.frame(readCount=1:1024)

# custom function to sample
mySample <- function(values, size, nElementsPerValue){
  nElementsPerValue <- as.integer(nElementsPerValue)
  if(sum(nElementsPerValue) < size)
    stop("Total number of elements per value is lower than the sample size")
  if(length(values) != length(nElementsPerValue))
    stop("nElementsPerValue must have the same length of values")
  if(any(nElementsPerValue < 0))
    stop("nElementsPerValue cannot contain a negative numbers")

  # remove values having zero elements inside
  nElementsPerValue <- nElementsPerValue[which(nElementsPerValue > 0)]
  values <- values[which(nElementsPerValue > 0)]

  # pre-allocate the result vector
  res <- rep.int(0.0,size)
  for(i in 1:size){
    idx <- sample(1:length(values),size=1,replace=F,prob=nElementsPerValue)
    res[i] <- values[idx]
    # remove sampled value from nElementsPerValue
    nElementsPerValue[idx] <- nElementsPerValue[idx] - 1
    # if zero elements remove also from values
    if(nElementsPerValue[idx] == 0){
      values <- values[-idx]
      nElementsPerValue <- nElementsPerValue[-idx]
    }
  }
  return(res)
}

# just for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# sample 100k values from readCount
system.time(
  a <- mySample(data$readCount, 100000, 1:1024), 
  gcFirst=T)

# on my machine it gives :
#   user  system elapsed 
#  10.63    0.00   10.67
```

Comment: Thanks! This appears to work, although I think you got it slightly backwards. My data have 1024 rows with different `readCounts` in each row representing the # of times that variable was seen in the analysis. So I was making a vector where if `readCounts` for row 1 was 10, my vector had 10 1's. Based on my understanding of your code, I used it exactly as is but swapped the inputs - `test <- mySample(1:1024, 1000, data$readCount)`

Comment: Yes, sorry I misread and interpreted it backwards. If you pass the arguments in the opposite order it should work :)